# what does the # sign mean in xml

Tags: xml, spring

I am pretty new to xml and spring and am trying to follow an xml file and I found these lines:

```
<bean id="urlResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource">
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.net.URL" value="classpath:config/config-#{environment}.properties" />
</bean>
```

I am not sure if the # is a feature of xml or a feature of spring. Does anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Spring feature. #{...} is an [SpEL expression](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#expressions-beandef-xml-based).

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for that for ever.